Texstudio: \begin{equation}... auto complete
In overleaf, I'm used to typing
\beg(in){eq(uation)}

(\end{equation})

where I marked the bits of code which is there due to autocomplete in brackets. So I basically type the beginning of begin, which it then autocompletes into begin+end. Then I can type in eq, and I can via enter-key autocomplete equation in both begin and end. My cursor also automatically jumps into the environment and I can immediately start typing.
The Texstudio behaviour is as follows:
It autocompletes begin and end. Then I can type into the braces the environment for both at the same time. But no matter what, I have to type out equation (or any other type of environment). And now I even have a placeholder text I have to delete manually, since without autocomplete, it doesn't jump to the content and marks it, such that I can immediately start typing my equations.
Is there a setting to change this behaviour?

See Options > Configure TeXstudio… Select Completion on the left panel. On my computer, all checkboxes are checked, and Preferred Commands Set is at Typical. You can pass placeholders with Ctr+arrow.

@NBur I do have all things checked. Is the behaviour different for you?

In the cwl files list, I have latex-document.cwl, pgf.cwl, pgfcore.cwl, pgfplots.cwl, siunitx.cwl, tcolorbox.cwl, tex.cwl, tikz.cwl checked

@NBur I tried to find what you are talking about, but I did not. I went into my appdata/roaming/texstudio/completion folder. In the autogenerated one, it only had one file, in the user one it had none. So how do I get these .cwl files and where is this cwl list you are talking about?

I mean, in TeXstudio, same place as mentioned.

@NBur Ah, I see, I had to click show advanced options to see that. I now activated all of what you listed, but I still cannot autocomplete the equation env. like in Overleaf.

Does this answer your question? I'll try to have a look on my other computer which behave like yours.
